# How to keep adding values at end of dictionary

Tags: python, xml, parsing, dictionary

I learnt python yesterday. I'm trying to parse an XML File and put the values in a dictionary.

```
xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
d ={ }
for child in root:
   d[child.tag] = child.attrib
   print child.tag, child.attrib
   print("\n")
for k,v in d.items():
   print(k,v)
```

Now the statement `d[child.tag] = child.attrib` is being rewritten everytime instead of being updated.

So the output i'm getting is --

```
country {'name': 'Liechtenstein'}
country {'name': 'Singapore'}
country {'name': 'Panama'}

('country', {'name': 'Panama'})
```

The first three lines of output are due to the `print()`. The last line is coming from dictionary.

How can i do this efficiently so that my dictionary stores all the three lines?

Comment: What format do you want your answer to end up in?

Comment: No specific format required. Anything will do. I just want all the three values of country to be saved with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for child in root:
    d[child.tag].append(child.attrib)
```

If all `root`'s  immediate children have the same tag then you could just use a list:

```
L = [child.attrib for child in root]
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard Python `dict` is unordered - so, you can't, unless you use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.1.html#pep-372-ordered-dictionaries) that is available in Python 3.1.

Comment: [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) is available in Python 2.7 There is a recipe for older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. If your only goal is to save the three countries, you're better off using a list than a dict. Dicts are for associating keys to values, and the keys must be distinct. You're using `name` as the key every time, which is why each entry is overwriting the former one.

So instead you could do something like

```
d = []
for child in root:
    d.append(child.attrib)
```

If you actually have distinct keys to which you want to associate certain values, then you can use a dict. But you have to be able to guarantee that the keys are distinct.